# Clarification sought on difference between casting a float to int in C# using a float literal vs a float variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting

Working in VS Code and Unity.

Below are 2 examples of casting a float to an int via a cast and 1 using a function.

```
float value = 0.94f;

Debug.Log($"Value : {value}");

int a = (int) (100 * 0.94f);

Debug.Log($"a : {a}");

int b = (int) (100 * value);

Debug.Log($"b : {b}");

int c = System.Convert.ToInt32(100 * value);

Debug.Log($"c : {c}");
```

---

Output is as follows:

```
Value : 0.94
a : 94
b : 93
c : 94
```

The only difference between (a) and (b) is that (a) is using a literal float, where as (b) is using a variable float.

My question is why is there is a difference in the output?
It it possible that using a variable is introducing some precision error?

Example (c) was added just to clarify that the correct result can be achieved using the same variable.

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: It was suggested that System.Single (the type given for a literal float) is an alias for a float type. Not sure it this gives any insight into the way it is handled internally. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/605a8cc6-250f-49ac-b431-671a7064151e/is-there-any-difference-between-float-and-single-type-of-variables-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: `Debug.Log` suggests that you are using Unity. Are you using Unity? I cannot reproduce using the Roslyn compiler with regular `Console.WriteLine`. If you are using Unity, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Valid point. I've added the tag to clarify. I am indeed working in Unity IDE. Maybe it's a Unity specific issue with my particular distro release if your not seeing similar behavour elsewhere.

Comment: I tested this code in Unity 2022.1.17 (on a mac m1) and got only `94` log entries

Comment: Also tested on Unity 2022.1.16 on a Windows Intel PC and there i *did* get the `93` log for `b`